# Traverse Nested Ruby Hash With Array of Keys

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashtable

Given a hash with n levels of nested values, a field name, and a path

```
contact = {
  "Email" => "bob@bob.com",
  "Account" => {
    "Exchange" => true,
    "Gmail" => false,
    "Team" => {
      "Closing_Sales" => "Bob Troy",
      "Record" => 1234
    }
  }
}

field = "Record"
path = ["Account", "Team"] #Must support arbitrary path length
```

How can one define a method that would retrieve the field value at the end of the path.

```
def get_value(hash, field, path)
  ?
end

get_value(contact, "Record", ["Account", "Team"])
=> 1234
```

Comment: Your question is well-written. Next time consider wait a bit longer before selecting an answer. Quick selections can discourage other answers and short-circuits those still working on answers. (You had already selected an answer before I started writing mine, however.)

Comment: Howdy @CarySwoveland - Thanks for the advice, I surely will do that next time.  Just started really using StackExchange so I am a bit of a noob.  Your answer was excellent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's regard the "field" as the last element of the "path". Then it's simply

```
def grab_it(h, path)
  h.dig(*path)
end

grab_it contact, ["Account", "Team", "Record"]
  #=> 1234 
grab_it contact, ["Account", "Team", "Rabbit"]
  #=> nil
grab_it(contact, ["Account", "Team"]
  # => {"Closing_Sales"=>"Bob Troy", "Record"=>1234} 
grab_it contact, ["Account"]
  #=> {"Exchange"=>true, "Gmail"=>false, "Team"=>{"Closing_Sales"=>"Bob Troy",
  #    "Record"=>1234}}
```

[Hash#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) was added in v2.3.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Array#inject`: to mean `hash['Account']['Team']` then, `return_value_of_inject['Record']`:

```
def get_value(hash, field, path)
  path.inject(hash) { |hash, x| hash[x] }[field]
end

get_value(contact, field, path) # => 1234
```

BTW, how about `get_value(contact, ['Account', 'Team', 'Record'])` ?

```
def get_value2(hash, path)
  path.inject(hash) { |hash, x| hash[x] }
end

get_value2(contact, ['Account', 'Team', 'Record']) # => 1234
```

or `get_value(contact, 'Account.Team.Record')`

```
def get_value3(hash, path)
  path.split('.').inject(hash) { |hash, x| hash[x] }
end

get_value3(contact, 'Account.Team.Record')   # => 1234
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_value(contact, field, path)
  path.inject(contact) {|p, j| p.fetch(j, {}) }.fetch(field, nil)
end
```

Comment: You can simplify a bit by writing `(path + [field]).inject(contact) {|p, j| p.fetch(j, {}) }`.